# Quickblox user's online status by lastRequestAt

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

In documentation i see this code to get user's last activity

Can someone help me to use it in swift?

```
QBUUser *user = ...;

NSInteger currentTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSInteger userLastRequestAtTimeInterval   = [[user lastRequestAt] timeIntervalSince1970];

// if user didn't do anything last 1 minute (60 seconds)    
if((currentTimeInterval - userLastRequestAtTimeInterval) > 60)
{ 
 // user is offline now
}
```

I am on chat dialog viewcontroller.

I get dialog id, recipientID etc etc

But how can i retrieve user's lastRequestAt field ?

```
QBUUser *user = ...;
```

What is this three dots? `...` what should i pass in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get user by id:

```
    QBRequest.userWithID(userID, successBlock: { (response : QBResponse, user: QBUUser?) -> Void in

       lastRequestAt = Int((user?.lastRequestAt?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)

}, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse) -> Void in
// Handle error
})
```